# How to make Meteor Cordova *NOT* fullscreen on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I run/build my Meteor web app with Cordova for iOS. Unfortunately, I get a full-screen app that covers the top status bar (that includes the carrier, time, battery etc.) I am trying to avoid it - have a regular (i.e. not fullscreen) app.

I've explicitly set the fullscreen preference to false:

```
App.setPreference('Fullscreen', false);
```

But still the app will take 100% of the screen height. I'm using ionic too, if it matters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is handled by the [status bar plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar):

```
App.setPreference("StatusBarOverlaysWebView", false);
```

So if you set this to false, the web view will no longer overlay the status bar and it will not be 'full screen'.

You also have a few other preferences to control the colour ot the status bar. From the status bar plugin docs:

> **StatusBarBackgroundColor** (color hex string, no default value). On iOS
>   7, set the background color of the statusbar by a hex string (#RRGGBB)
>   at startup. If this value is not set, the background color will be
>   transparent.
>
> `<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />`
>
> **StatusBarStyle** (status bar style, defaults to lightcontent). On iOS 7,
>   set the status bar style. Available options default, lightcontent,
>   blacktranslucent, blackopaque.
>
> `<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />`

The only difference between the docs, aimed at Cordova, and Meteor is the preferences are set using `App.setPreference` in your `mobile-config.js` file instead of `<preference name=...`. in a `config.xml`

You can use the Cordova notation if you [build your own config.xml](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#advanced-build-customization) but it should not be necessary as the Meteor notation is able to pass these along to the `config.xml` it builds for you in the background.